# 4 shapes in a flag how to?

Tags: animation

I'm a newbie here but willing to learn.

I have 4 shapes that make 1 flag.
I've "compound path" in illustrator and exported it to SVG.
The flag with the wind added on it does not hold the 4 shapes all together.

[image: screenshot]

Blend file: http://www.makconcept.com/temp/4shape-flag.blend

Comment: Do you want the flag to have 'Missing' (transparent) areas, or is it supposed to be contiguous?

Comment: Thanks Robin for writing!
I've tried the continuous flag.. with a white background.... don't like it... 
I really want the missing transparency to be as is... but waving like 1 real full flag :)... can this be done?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Thanks Duarte :)

Comment: @Sandra Did you read everything Duarte Farrajota Ramos wrote? Not just the first sentence, right? ;-) What about an image? A screenshot? Maybe add it right to your question next time for everyone to see? *hint hint hint*

Comment: @Sandra: i am sorry but i cannot download your blend file. would be great if you could upload here: https://blend-exchange.com/ (that's the "official" way to provide blend files here)

Comment: Sorry guys for not following protocol from the start. I've uploaded the file to : blend-exchange.com 

Thanks

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=41Kr4Ymb" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/41Kr4Ymb/)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a special reason for islands of geometry, it would be much simpler to use a texture, to mask transparency.

- The cloth simulator *is* a simulator. Give it 4 pieces of cloth, and they will behave as 4 pieces of cloth. So you have to tell the simulator, somehow, you want the behaviour of a single rectangle.
- The flag should be provided to the simulator ready to be deformed by forces, not in an already deformed state
- The topology matters. The 'cloth' is modelled as (a fancy version of)  point-masses at the vertices, connected by edges interpreted as springs. A nice even density of points connected by edges of about the same length will behave more like real-world fabric.

So it would be easier to make the flag an evenly subdivided plane of one material.

Either in your 2D graphics package, or Blender, create a transparency mask at the same aspect ratio as your flag (easiest in pure black and pure white), and save it as pixels:

[image]

In an orthogonal view, UV unwrap your plane with 'Project fron View > Bounds'.

Plug the texture into the alpha channel of the flag's material, for an EEVEE render. (You will have to set the material's Blend Mode to allow transparency.)

[image]

This should give you more flexibility with your simulation.

[image]